# Bug with sorting and trimming user input

Tags: java, sorting

so I have this code which is meant to compare whether 2 user inputs are anagrams. However, when i run the code and type in specific inputs, the program does not sort the inputs alphabetically properly. This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Anagram {


  public static String sort(String s) {

    char[] sorted = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(sorted);
    return new String(sorted);
  }

  public static String tidy(String s) {

    String newInput = String.valueOf(s).toLowerCase().replaceAll("^[0-9A-Za-z]", "").trim();
    return newInput;
  }

  public static String tidy2(String s) {

    String newInput2 = String.valueOf(s).toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^0-9A-Za-z]", "").trim();
    return newInput2;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter line: ");
    String inputLine = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter anagram: ");
    String inputAnagram = keyboard.nextLine();

    inputLine = sort(inputLine);
    inputLine = tidy(inputLine);
    inputAnagram = sort(inputAnagram);
    inputAnagram = tidy(inputAnagram);

    System.out.println(inputLine);
    System.out.println(inputAnagram);

  }
}
```

When i input a name such as "Robert Gray" or anything with capital letters, it still seems to sort the capitalised letters first. However, when i switch the sort and tidy method in the main method body around, it works fine. Is there a reason for this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: sort method sorts the values bases on ASCII value. Since ascii value of Capital letters is less then the lower case letter thats the reason capital letters comes first. You can call `tidy` first and then sort it. that will give you the correct result.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sort method, you are doing Arrays.sort method which sorts based on the ASCII values. Capital letters appear before the small letters in the sorted order. However when you call your tidy method first and then the sort method it works because you are calling String class method toLowerCase on the string which converts all the capital letters to lower case. Later when you call the sort method, it works fine because all the letters are now in small case. In order to fix your problem, before calling the sort method, just convert your input and anagram String objects to lower case. Let me know if it still doesn't work.